FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND
FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND after FT_CyclePort in run-time, but when I check by debugger step by step no error.
OS Windows 10 Pro 22H2 x64. CPU AMD FX(tm)-8320 Eight-Core Processor 2.91 GHz RAN 16 Gb.
Compiler: Embarcadero C++ 7.50 for Win64 (RAD Studio 10.4.2).
Build target Windows any, both Win32and Win64, the effect occurs independently.
Hardware is FTDI FT245R.
A sample (seems to be senseless, just for demo) code is the following:
TForm1::OpenP`bool __fastcaort(void) { 
FT_STATUS ftStatus; 
ULONG Status;
ULONG BaudRate;
UCHAR WordLength;
UCHAR StopBits;
USHORT FlowControl;
UCHAR XonChar;
UCHAR XoffChar;


//FT245R USB FIFO
ftStatus = FT_OpenEx((PVOID)"FT245R USB FIFO",FT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION,&ftHandle);
if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
{   Application->MessageBox(L"Open port error in FT_Open", MB_OK);
    return false;
}
    
ftStatus = FT_CyclePort(ftHandle); //!!
Application->ProcessMessages();
Sleep(100);
if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
{   Application->MessageBox(L"Error while FT_CyclePort", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}

ftStatus=FT_Close(ftHandle);

Sleep(100);
Application->ProcessMessages();
if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
{   Application->MessageBox(L"Error while Close Device 2", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}
Sleep(100);
Application->ProcessMessages();

ftStatus=FT_Rescan();
if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
{   Application->MessageBox(L"FT_Rescan failed 2", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}
Application->ProcessMessages();
Sleep(100);

ftStatus = FT_OpenEx((PVOID)"FT245R USB FIFO",FT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION,&ftHandle);
if (ftStatus != FT_OK)
{   switch (ftStatus)
    {   case FT_INVALID_HANDLE:
           Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_INVALID_HANDLE", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        case FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND:
            Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        case FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED:
            Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        case FT_IO_ERROR:
            Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_IO_ERROR", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        case FT_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES:
            Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        case FT_INVALID_PARAMETER:
            Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_INVALID_PARAMETER", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        case FT_INVALID_BAUD_RATE:
            Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_INVALID_BAUD_RATE", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        case FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED_FOR_ERASE:
            Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error T_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED_FOR_ERASE", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        case FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED_FOR_WRITE:
            Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error  FT_DEVICE_NOT_OPENED_FOR_WRITE", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        case FT_FAILED_TO_WRITE_DEVICE:
           Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_FAILED_TO_WRITE_DEVICE", L"Error", MB_OK);
            break;
        default :
           Application->MessageBox(L"FT_OpenEx failed with error", L"Error", MB_OK);

    }
    return false;
}
else
    return true;
} 

If I put break point before second FT_OpenEx and go line by line in debug mode then everything is Ok.
Unlike in rintime i've got an error "FT_OpenEx failed with error FT_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND" even with delay of Sleep(1000) after reconnect device by FT_CyclePort.
